# Java - Alterar XML e depois ler

Tags: java, xml, javafx, jdom

Eu tenho uma aplicação que escreve em um XML e uma que lê, as duas funcionam bem separadamente, mas o problema é que quando eu escrevo no XML, a outra aplicação continua lendo sem atualizar os dados, como se o arquivo não tivesse sido atualizado(mas foi).

Segue o código:

```
public int lerXml() throws JDOMException, IOException {
    File f = new File("c:/xml.xml");
    SAXBuilder sb = new SAXBuilder();
    Document d;
    try {
        d = sb.build(f);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 0;
    }
    Element mural = d.getRootElement();
    List elements = mural.getChildren();
    Iterator i = elements.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Element element = (Element) i.next();
        if (Double.parseDouble(element.getChildText("tempo")) >= mediaPlayer.getCurrentTime().toSeconds()) {
            System.out.println("Nome:" + element.getChildText("nome"));
            System.out.println("Tempo:" + element.getChildText("tempo"));
            System.out.println("Menssagem:" + element.getChildText("conteudo"));
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

**OBS:** Sem o Try-Catch ali na linha do  **d = sb.build(f);** imediatamente quando eu escrevo no xml aprece um erro assim:

> org.jdom2.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1 of document file:/c:/xml.xml: Fim prematuro do arquivo.

**OBS²:** essa função fica em uma Thread rodando sem parar.

EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------

Leitura:

```
public int lerXml() throws JDOMException, IOException {
    File f = new File("c:/smh/xml.xml");
    if (f.exists()) {
        SAXBuilder sb = new SAXBuilder();
        Document d;

        try {
            d = sb.build(f);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return 0;
        }
        Element mural = d.getRootElement();
        List elements = mural.getChildren();
        Iterator i = elements.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Element element = (Element) i.next();
            if (Double.parseDouble(element.getChildText("tempo")) >= mediaPlayer.getCurrentTime().toSeconds()) {
                //System.out.println("Nome:" + element.getChildText("nome"));
                //System.out.println("Tempo:" + element.getChildText("tempo"));
                System.out.println("Menssagem:" + element.getChildText("conteudo"));
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Escrita:

```
private void xml(String name, Double currentTime, String comment) throws JDOMException, IOException {
    File f1 = new File(PATH);
    File f2 = new File(PathTemp);
    copyFile(f1, f2);
    f1.delete();
    Document myDocument = lerArquivo(PathTemp);
    Element comentarios = myDocument.getRootElement();
    Element comentario = new Element("comentario");
    comentario.setAttribute("id", "1");

    Element nome = new Element("nome");
    nome.setText(name);
    Element tempo = new Element("tempo");
    tempo.setText(currentTime.toString());
    Element conteudo = new Element("conteudo");
    conteudo.setText(comment);

    comentario.addContent(nome);
    comentario.addContent(tempo);
    comentario.addContent(conteudo);
    comentarios.addContent(comentario);
    Format format = Format.getPrettyFormat();
    format.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    XMLOutputter xout = new XMLOutputter(format);

    try {
        xout.output(myDocument, System.out);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        FileWriter arquivo = new FileWriter(new File(PATH));
        xout.output(myDocument, arquivo);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    copyFile(f2, f1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Provavelmente o seu principal problema e que um o aplicativo de leitura esta lendo o arquivo ao mesmo tempo em que o de escrita esta escrevendo, isso pode acarretar no  org.jdom2.input.JDOMParseException.

Tente colocar seu código de uma maneira que o leitor não leia o arquivo enquanto o escritor esta escrevendo, uma sugestão simples é antes do escritor começar a escrever o arquivo ele apaga o arquivo original, faz a escrita com no arquivo com um outro nome e quando ele terminar colocar o arquivo com o nome certo, no leitor apenas faça uma verificação se o arquivo existem antes de começar a ler.

Comment: Vou tentar isso, obrigado!

Comment: Tentei e não deu certo, vou colocar o código novo no post.